# how to write function to get value through 2 data frames using iteration in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got two data frames, A of length 2173 and B of length 6135. 
A is called 'file_name', B is called 'crsp_name'

```py
A.head()
                    file_name
0                       3M CO
1         ABBOTT LABORATORIES
2                     ABC INC
3            ALTRIA GROUP INC
4  AMERICAN ELECTRIC POWER CO
B.head()
0      A & E PLASTIK PAK INC
1    A & M FOOD SERVICES INC
2                 A A I CORP
3          A A IMPORTING INC
4                 A A R CORP
Name: comnam, dtype: object
```

I was trying to compute the fuzz.token_set_ratio of every element in A with B and combine them as one data frame.For example, compute the ratio of "3M CO" with every element in B, and combine "3M" and the largest ratio as one row in a data frame. in this way, I was expected to get a data frame of shape(2173,2)

Here is my function, I try to use 'apply' and my 'fuzzratio' function to compute the desired ratio. But there was an error, hope someone can provide me a right solution.

```py
def fuzzratio(x):
    global crsp_name
    ratio_list = list()
    name_list = list()
    for i in crsp_name:
        ratio = fuzz.token_set_ratio(x,i)
        if ratio > 80:
            name_list.append(x)
            ratio_list.append(ratio)
    name_list = pd.DataFrame(name_list)
    result = pd.merge(name_list,ratio_list).rename(columns = {'comnam','ratio'})
    return result

file_name.apply(fuzzratio)
```

error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6004, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 318, in get_result
    return super(FrameRowApply, self).get_result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 142, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 248, in apply_standard
    self.apply_series_generator()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 277, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in fuzzratio
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 60, in merge
    validate=validate)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 526, in __init__
    'type {right}'.format(right=type(right)))
ValueError: ("can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'list'>", 'occurred at index file_name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created test data the following way:

```
dat_A="""file_name
3M CO
ABBOTT LABORATORIES
ABC INC
ALTRIA GROUP INC
AMERICAN ELECTRIC POWER CO"""

dat_B="""crsp_name
A & E PLASTIK PAK INC
A & M FOOD SERVICES INC
A A I CORP
A A IMPORTING INC
A A R CORP
ABBOTT
ABBOTT LABS
ALTRIA
ALTRIA GROUP"""

df_A = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(dat_A))
df_B = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(dat_B))
```

Because from *df_B* there is used only *crsp_name* column, for efficiency
reason I extracted it into *crsp* variable:

```
crsp = df_B.crsp_name
```

For easier manipulation with the ratio threshold, I saved it as another variable:

```
ratio_threshold = 50
```

For test purpose I took a lower value in order to get any "non-empty"
results, but for your data set it back at **80** (the value which you defined).

Then we define the function to be applied soon:

```
def fn(t1):
    ratios = crsp.apply(lambda t2: fuzz.token_set_ratio(t1, t2))
    iMax = ratios.idxmax()
    rMax = ratios[iMax]
    return crsp.loc[iMax] if rMax > ratio_threshold else f'{iMax}_{rMax}'
```

This function will be applied to each string from *df_A.file_name*,
so *t1* is the current value (*file_name*).

The function starts from computing token set ratios between the current
*file_name* and each *crsp_name* (saved in *ratios*).

Then *iMax* is computed as the index of max ratio and *rMax* - the
max ratio itself.

If the max ratio is above our threshold, the function returns
the respective *crsp_name*.

Otherwise the function returns a "diagnostic message" - *x_y* (2 numbers)
where *x* is the index where the max ratio has been found and
*y* - the ratio itself. In the final version of the program change
it to either *np.nan* or an empty string.

And the only thing to do is to apply this function and add the result
as a new column to *df_A*:

```
df_A['crsp_name'] = df_A.file_name.apply(fn)
```

For the above test data (and the threshold == 50) I got:

```
                    file_name              crsp_name
0                       3M CO                   2_46
1         ABBOTT LABORATORIES                 ABBOTT
2                     ABC INC  A & E PLASTIK PAK INC
3            ALTRIA GROUP INC                 ALTRIA
4  AMERICAN ELECTRIC POWER CO                   1_43
```

As you can see, there are still 2 cases where no position
in *crsp_name* gave ratio over 50, but the reason is that
source data is very limited.

## Second solution

When the task is to find a match against a **list of candidates**,
a better (quicker) solution is to use *process.extractOne*.

As it takes a **list** as the second argument, I extracted *values*
from *crsp* into another variable:

```
crspVals = crsp.values
```

The function to match (returning only the best match) is:

```
def fn3(t1):
    res = process.extractOne(t1, crspVals, scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio,
        score_cutoff=ratio_threshold)
    return res[0] if res else ''
```

`process.extractOne` returns a **tuple** (best match, ratio), but if
no match above the threshold has been found, the result is *None*,
so I decided to give up the best ratio below the threshold, and return
only the best match or an empty string.

To apply this function, run:

```
df_A['crsp_name'] = df_A.file_name.apply(fn3)
```

Compared to the first solution (modified to return only *crsp_name*)
it runs almost 2 times quicker.